# Maximum number of arguments in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

MDN says that

> A function can have up to 255 arguments.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

But actually it can have even more

```
var params = _.range(2048);
var $ul = $('ul');
var items = '';
var template = _.template("<li>Arg # <%- arg %></li>");

function foo() {
    _.each(arguments, function (arg) {
        items += template({arg: arg});
    });

    $ul.html(items);
}

foo.apply(foo, params);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dtseen4v/

What is wrong?

Comment: Implementations are allowed to go beyond the requirements.

Comment: I can't find a mention of the 255 argument limit (or any other limit) in ECMAScript 5.1 spec or ECMAScript 6 draft. I'm not sure where MDN got that from.

Comment: there might be a formal parameter limit of 255 in FF, but `arguments` is not limited; so the apply() works. i think 8 is a good enough limit for formal parameters, nobody should be hand-passing hundreds of args...